# ¿ Por qué no me reconoce las etiquetas del CSS?

Tags: css, html5

Estoy empezando en esto de la programación y me he encontrado con un problema que no sé como solucionar. Estoy intentando crear una página web con ayuda de tutoriales de youtube y lo sigo paso a paso, empecé con un documento html. Hasta aquí todo perfecto pero en el archivo css para crear los estilos llegan los problemas. Por ejemplo si hago un estilo para algo en general como body. EJ: body{background-color:red;} eso si me funciona pero a la hora de hacer etiquetas no me las reconoce por más que las escriba 20 veces o de diferentes maneras.  Es decir todo lo que sea con etiquetas no me funciona.
Código html:

```
<html>

     <head>
             
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=a.css>
             <title> Motos </title>
             
     </head>

     <body>
            <header>
                     <hgroup>
                         <h1><center>
                           <strong> Motos de segunda mano </strong>
                       </center> </h1>
                         <h2><center> La página web más fiable</center></h2>
                      </hgroup>    
            </header>
          
            <nav id:"qa">
                <ul>
                    <li> ¿Quíenes somos? </li>
                    <li> Nuestros productos </li>
                    <li> Profesionales </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section>
                      <header 
                         <p> <b><a target= href=pagina2.htlm>kymko</a> Like 125cc 1400E</b>
                      </header>
                         <hr>
                         <br> <u>Se encuentra en perfecto estado con 7000 km.</u>
                         <br> <u>No se le ha dado casi uso.Precio no negociable </u></br>
                         <img alt= kymko like width= 300px src=moto.jpg>
                         <figcaption><small>KYMKO LIKE</small></figcaption>
             </section>
             <footer> Derechos reservados para el autor. 
             
             </footer>
    
     </body>
</html>
```

Y el código CSS:

```
body{background-color: grey}
footer{background-color: blue}
#qa{background-color: red; float-left; height:1000px;}
```

Los dos primeros me funcionan, pero el tercero que es una etiqueta no me funciona.Alguien tendría una solución ?
Muchas gracias !

Comment: Hola @RAMON! Podes editar tu pregunta y agrega tu código **html** y **css** por favor. Y de paso dale una mirada a [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola ! voy a editar la pregunta y a subir los documentos. Muchas gracias !!!

Comment: Ya lo he editado

Comment: @RAMON, en lugar de poner <nav id:"qa"> , tienes que ponerlo con "igual", es decir: <nav id="qa">. Todos los atributos y propiedades en HTML deben asignarse mediante este "operador".

Comment: Muchas gracias cooper !!!! Como tú dices si funciona ! Cómo hago para poner tu respuesta destacada ?

Comment: Tendría que escribir una respuesta, esto son comentarios... pero cuando el problema es un error tipográfico, generalmente las preguntas se cierran, lo siento

Comment: Recuerda que los atributos van entre comillas. Por ejemplo, `<img alt="kymko like" width="300px" src="moto.jpg">`, y sin espacios extra.

Answer (score 3):

En los comentarios te deje las explicaciones de lo que te faltaba.
Fijate en aca como hacer una estructura basica de HTML [link](https://gist.github.com/mvallez/7138379)

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}

#qa {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- en el href te faltan las comillas -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
  <title>Motos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <h1>
        <center>
          <strong>Motos de segunda mano</strong>
        </center>
      </h1>
      <h2>
        <center>La página web más fiable</center>
      </h2>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
<!-- aqui tendria que ser = en lugar del : -->
  <nav id="qa">
    <ul>
      <li>¿Quíenes somos?</li>
      <li>Nuestros productos</li>
      <li>Profesionales</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <!-- pues aqui te falta > del header -->
    <header>
      <!-- aqui te faltaria cerrar tu </p> y tambien las comillas en el href y elimite el target-->
      <p><b><a href="pagina2.html">kymko</a> Like 125cc 1400E</b></p>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <br><u>Se encuentra en perfecto estado con 7000 km.</u>
    <br><u>No se le ha dado casi uso.Precio no negociable</u><br>
    <img alt="k ymko like" width="300px" src="moto.jpg">
    <figcaption><small>KYMKO LIKE</small></figcaption>
  </section>
  <footer>
  Derechos reservados para el autor.
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Desconocía de está sintaxis float-left; en la regla css

Comment: Había varios errores tipográficos, los he corregido, no era float-left; sino float: left, he cerrado entre comillas los atributos, añadidos puntos y coma y eliminados espacios innecesarios. En general, es importante asegurarse de una buena sintaxis, de lo contrario te vas a volver loco intentando encontrar que falla, los editores de texto con resaltado de sintaxis y/o coloreado, ayudan mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Así el código te debería de funcionar: Cerrando las comillas en el Href. Recomiendo que leas esta dcumentación sobre [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Como_se_estructura_CSS#) y esta sobre [HTML](https://www.hazunaweb.com/curso-de-html/estructura-basica-una-pagina-web/).

```html
<html>

     <head>
             
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
             <title> Motos </title>
             
     </head>

     <body>
            <header>
                     <hgroup>
                         <h1><center>
                           <strong> Motos de segunda mano </strong>
                       </center> </h1>
                         <h2><center> La página web más fiable</center></h2>
                      </hgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un error tan simple que no escribiste bien el id.
Tu lo escribiste así:

```
id:"qa"
```

Y en realidad no puede ser dos puntos ya que no estas programando con VueJS.
Así que tiene que ser de la siguiente manera:

```
id="qa"
```

Espero haber ayudado y que quede claro.

Comment: Las preguntas cuyo error es un typo no se deberían responder pues terminan cerradas